# What are functions with "memory"?

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm trying to understand what functions with "memory" are. An example would be this:

```
;; add : number -> (number -> number)
;; to create a function that adds x to its input
(define (add x)
(local ((define (x-adder y) (+ x y))) x-adder))
```

When I run this with e.g. (add 4) I just get "function:x-adder". I don't understand the purpose of this function or for what it would be good for.
Why is the function above a function with "memory" and  what exactly is a function with "memory"?

We defined functions with "memory" as functions combined with local and higher order functions. But I don't get it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you want to add 30 to a one digit number:

```
(+ 30 5)
; ==> 35
```

You can make it a function:

```
(define (add30 x)
  (+ 30 x))
```

But perhaps you have many functions like that so you make a function that just takes the first thing to add and return a function that takes the second number.. That is your `add`. You can make `add30` like this:

```
(define add30 (add 30))
```

Now imagine you want to add 30 to a whole list:

```
(define (digit-list->ascii-list lst)
  (map (add 30) lst))
```

So what is `(add 30)` well.. It returns an `x-adder` where`x` is bound to `30`. `map` just supplies the one argument and it becomes 30+y. You could say the resulting function remembers `30`, but the technical term is that the variable that is 30 has been closed over. The returned function is a closure.

Comment: Thank you. Quick question: If I want to use my add function above, I have to call the x-adder with a number (y)  e.g. (x-adder 2), right? Just x-adder doesnt do anything.

Comment: @JacquesH It's a function value. `add1` and `(add 1)` can be used in the same manner eg. `(map add1 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4)` and `(map (add 1) '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4)`. the value from evaluating `(add 1)` is a function, just like the value from evaluating `add1`. they do equally as much as function values when not applied.